# Pass value in KendoGrid template function

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to pass the value of the row
into the template function

```
{
    field: "RuleName",
    template: ruleRadioActive(<MyValueHere>),
    title: global.textJSPartialView["RuleName"],    
    headerTemplate: *bla bla*
}
```

I want to pass the "RuleName" value to the function *ruleRadioActive*.
I've tried using `"#= RuleName #"` but it will pass the string and not the value.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I discovered that using a function in the template option
 automatically sends the object with the whole row structure to the function.

So if I have:

```
{
    field: "RuleName",
    template: templateFunction,
    title: global.textJSPartialView["RuleName"],    
    headerTemplate: *bla bla*
}
```

and I want to print a `<p>` with some value in it
the function `templateFunction` will look something like this:

```
function templateFunction(DataItem){
    return "<p>" + DataItem.<element in structure> + "</p>";
}
```